# Javascript performance of indexing

Tags: javascript, performance

Is the following line considered unoptimal, especially considering it is being used in many places or inside of a loop:

```
var age = myObject[index]["Person"]["Identity"]["Bio"]["Age"]
```

Comment: You'd have to show us the rest of your loop for us to make a specific code suggestion.  But, yes, usually you do not want to repeatedly do the same object lookups over and over again if it can be avoided with an intermediate variable.

Comment: the solution you are using is exactly 23.521% slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if hash lookup in Javascript is O(1) (I don't know for sure), you'd still have the overhead of the lookup operations. So, yes, this is suboptimal for a big loop.